# Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW seems to not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, jpa

Using Spring (MVC, Batch, and persistence) I have the following piece of an interface defined:

```
public interface JobStatusService {
  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  @Modifying
  JobStatus save(JobStatus status);

  @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  Optional<JobStatus> get(ResultsIdentifier identifier);
}
```

Note the `REQUIRES_NEW` as it's on the broken method.

This interface is implemented in:

```
@Override
public JobStatus save(JobStatus status) {
    if (status.getUserId() == null) {
        status.setUserId(userService.getCurrentUser());
    }
    status.setLastUpdateTime(new Date());
    return repository.save(status);
}

@Override
public Optional<JobStatus> get(ResultsIdentifier identifier) {
    return repository.findByJobIdentifier(identifier);
}
```

Where repository is a JPA repository with the following:

```
public interface JobStatusRepository extends Repository<JobStatus, ResultsIdentifier> {

  JobStatus save(JobStatus status);

  Optional<JobStatus> findByJobIdentifier(ResultsIdentifier id);
}
```

`ResultsIdentifier` is a simple compound ID class of a string code and an ID number.

Elsewhere, I have a batch Writer finishing out by writing a JobStatus to the repository, and a web Controller class which runs a loop containing a query to the job status service. The `save()` operation seems to execute correctly, and the `get()` operation works right *the first time*.

However, if the first run of the loop calls `get()` and the JobStatus isn't "complete" then on all subsequent runs it *still* is not "complete". And in fact the same exact object comes back from Hibernate (which is my persistence tool under the hood). What's happening is that the session cache in `SessionImpl`/`StatefulPersistenceContext` is keeping a copy of it and always returning that instead of doing a real database query. So, I figured, `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` should always start a new transaction/session, right? But the same problem recurs whether I include that in the annotation or not.

Are the life-cycles of the session and transaction not coterminous here? If not, how can I tell Spring I want to start a new *session*? I'm trying to avoid changing my XML configs to push the Hibernate session factory into the JobStatusService implementation and manually `clear()` it, as no other part of the system sees Hibernate directly.

I'm also happy to hear any suggestions for debugging session-related stuff, given that in my code it's just a magic annotation.

I eventually "solved" this by setting fetch to EAGER on a particular entity definition. This doesn't seem like it should work, so I put in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758262/changing-fetch-to-eager-seems-to-fix-unrelated-session-caching-problems) to inquire what might have happened.

Comment: Are you sure you can put the @Transactional annotation on the interface? It seems wrong to me and I think you should put it on the implementation of the methods in the bean class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but applying it to the implementing class instead didn't change anything. And debugging step-throughs confirm that while the Propagation part isn't doing what I expected, the basic `@Transactional` aspect works fine, proxy classes are being made, etc.